# Menu above the status bar on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Does anyone know how to solve this image problem?
All content is correct, below the bar, but when the menu is open it is on top.

Second question: Is it possible to change the text color of the status bar from black to white?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the following [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/)

Regarding the first issue you can check if the statusbar is visible and if the operation system is iOS, then you can add a class to the menu. With this class you can add `padding-top: 20px`.

About the second issue, please check the plugin properties. You can manipulate some of the statusbar's properties.

Answer (score 1):

if the platform is iOS .Open the project using Xcode .Select the General tab and on Deployment option you can see option to hide the status bar or you can uncheck the requires full screen